# Mp4 file from Url is taking too long to play

Tags: java, android

I have a mp4 Url, which is containing 400mb of video.
Using exoplayer, it's taking too long (10-15 min) for start the playing the video.
I have added loadcontrol but no use. Can anybody help me ?

```
  MediaSource videoSource = new 
  ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(mUri);
    // Prepare the player with the source.
    Log.d("exo","to be prepare");
    player.prepare(videoSource);
    Log.d("exo","prepared"+videoSource);

    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    Log.d("exo","played");

    player.addListener(this);

============================
```

LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl(
new DefaultAllocator(true, 16),
VideoPlayerConfig.MIN_BUFFER_DURATION,
VideoPlayerConfig.MAX_BUFFER_DURATION,
VideoPlayerConfig.MIN_PLAYBACK_START_BUFFER,
VideoPlayerConfig.MIN_PLAYBACK_RESUME_BUFFER, -1, true);

```
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
                new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector =
                new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
        // 2. Create the player
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(new DefaultRenderersFactory(this), trackSelector, loadControl);
        videoFullScreenPlayer.setPlayer(player);
```

Comment: Could you please add some code snippets of what you are doing?

Comment: @vs97 Please check the code. This code is working fine if the url is having of video 100-200mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented CDN and it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

This might have multiple causes:

**1. The max buffer duration is too large**

Try to play with setting a lower value for `VideoPlayerConfig.MAX_BUFFER_DURATION` (which is `30 seconds` [apparently](https://www.loopwiki.com/application/android-streaming-video-with-exoplayer-2/))

**2. Your streaming video protocol is not efficient**

It possibly has to do with the video encoding in combination with your network speed limitations. I'm guessing that the video player is loading the entire video, or at least a massive chunk of it) before it plays. That's why Protocols like "HTTP Live Stream" solve this problem and lead to videos playing nearly instantly, as the protocol sends chunks of videos, and adjusts the bandwidth dynamically.

**3. Your internet connection is relatively slow**

While this is probably not the main cause, it might affect the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ken
**1.** I configured `VideoPlayerConfig.MAX_BUFFER_DURATION` in my code. That is  `final int MAX_BUFFER_DURATION = 5000;` 

**2.** I'll try with HLS player. But I think it needs to modify the url as well. I have mp4 URL.

**3.** I checked this scenario. But internet is much better in the phone. In other apps like netflix and prime, it's playing fine

Comment: I am not convinced that changing to HLS player will fix your protocol issue. I've seen instant loads of video on Android and iOS with ExoPlayer. It's the server that hosts the MP4 video that might need to provide a proper streaming protocol.

Comment: The solution is to implement CDN. Which can provide a url to play with video encoding. Thank !!